# Replace header in a word document containing a table and image from header in a different word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have lots of word documents that are set up with incorrect headers. The header on the first page is correct; however, the headers on the remaining pages are incorrect. I have been working on writing a program using XML SDK in C# that more or less copies the document and replaces the header in the original with the header on the first page in the copy.

The issue I am having is the header is basically a table with images and text in it. From what I can tell, the table and the image along with their relationships are not merging into the new document. Do you have any code examples or advice on how to merge tables with images into the header of a document?

Comment: Mmm, in order to understand this you need to learn how the Word Open XML file format works. It's not a single document - not everything is stored in the HeaderPart. I recommend you open the document in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to see what's going on. A header such as you describe comes in three parts: the "text", the media files and the "rels" that ties them together. The table should be coming across with the content of the Header part, but the images will be stored separately and need to be streamed in separately. In addition, the relationships need to be created (the rels file).

Comment: You might want to reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617372/i-am-merging-two-word-documents-with-openxml-sdk-but-get-a-corrupt-document-when / https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7e34c135-361a-44cb-a9df-e6246f6ca781/copy-header-with-image-from-a-docx-file-to-another-using-open-xml-and-c?forum=oxmlsdk

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Word Macro for this kind of thing?  I'm sure you can do it in C#, but it seems unnecessarily difficult in this scenario.

http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html

http://software-solutions-online.com/word-vba-modify-header-for-multiple-files/